# How to accept user input from a pop-up?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android and just in the learning stage and have a query, would be great if you can answer.

My first app I'm trying to make is about counting scores, it also has a scoreboard page which displays which player score how much. What I would like to do is accept the name of the player during run time, probably using a pop-up, and as soon as player-1 is out, pop-up again to get second player's name.

Here's the code:

activity_scoreboard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list_of_players"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.cricketcounter.Scoreboard">

</ListView>
```

Scoreboard.java:

```
package com.example.android.cricketcounter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Scoreboard extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scoreboard);

        ArrayList<Players> players = new ArrayList<>();
        players.add(new Players("Abc",0,0));  //I would like to pass in the user-inputted value instead of Abc here.
        players.add(new Players("Def",0,0));

        PlayerAdapter playerAdapter = new PlayerAdapter(this, players);
        ListView playerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_of_players);
        playerList.setAdapter(playerAdapter);
    }

}
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/name"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/runsA"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ballsA"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Players.java

```
package com.example.android.cricketcounter;

/**
 * Created by Abhijeet on 01-07-2017.
 */

public class Players {

    private String mPlayerName;
    private int mRuns;
    private int mBalls;

    public Players(String playerName, int runs, int balls){
        mPlayerName = playerName;
        mRuns = runs;
        mBalls = balls;
    }

    public String getPlayerName(){
        return mPlayerName;
    }

    public int getRuns(){
        return mRuns;
    }

    public int getBalls() {
        return mBalls;
    }
}
```

PlayerAdapter.java:

```
package com.example.android.cricketcounter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Abhijeet on 01-07-2017.
 */

public class PlayerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Players> {

    public PlayerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Players> players){
        super(context, 0, players);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        Players currentPlayer = getItem(position);

        TextView playerName = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        playerName.setText(currentPlayer.getPlayerName());

        TextView runsScored = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.runsA);
        runsScored.setText(String.valueOf(currentPlayer.getRuns()));

        TextView ballsTaken = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.ballsA);
        ballsTaken.setText(String.valueOf(currentPlayer.getBalls()));

        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends on how you are using popup

Comment: Here is the one way of doing, ->When player gets out, dialogbox to get players name ->Store that name in your list of database depending on your need, and then `notifyDataSetChanged()`